# Refreshing a div using .load() function

Tags: html, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#container').load('contents/home.html');
$('#nav ul#navigation li a').click(function(){
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#container').fadeOut('slow').load('contents/' + page + '.html').fadeIn('slow');
        return false;
    });
});
```

This works good when loading pages within a div *container*.
**`home.html`** containing *`nivoSlider`*, when the whole page is refreshing it works good but loading **`home.html`** again onto **`#container`** after loading  pages using function
**`$('#container').load('contents/' + page + '.html')`** then the *`nivoSlider`* isn't not working.
I have to refresh the whole page just to refresh the `div`. So I need a code to refresh the `div` every time it load the pages onto the div **`#container`**.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to encapsulate unique knowledge in a single place in your code. If you need to refresh something, make sure to put this in a single place and then call it as required. Your code could look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var container = $('#container');
    function loadContent(url, callback) {
        return container.load(url, {}, function () {
            // Add code here to refresh nivoSlider

            // Run a callback if exists
            if (callback) {
                callback();
            }
        });
    }
    loadContent('contents/home.html');

    $('#nav ul#navigation li a').click(function (event) {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        container.fadeOut('slow').loadContent('contents/' + page + '.html').fadeIn('slow');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```